# How important are correct spellings (grammar), when they do not affect the understanding of message?

Tags: discussion, questions, grammatical-correction

Example: [iframe cross domain dom handeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082774/iframe-cross-domain-dom-handeling)

I am an English language enthusiast and quite a large number of questions have minor grammatical and spelling errors. They do not in any case hinder the understanding of the question.

Possible reasons could indicate a general level of expertise with the language, or a certain degree of carelessness.

Does the Community encourage tidying up of spelling/grammar, even if it adds little programming value?

Comment: If you think other readers will not be able to understand the question when you understand it,it is best to edit it because there are people in SO who don't speak English

Comment: Okay, what would you say about the linked question? e.g. 'dom' should be 'DOM', 'handeling' spellling is wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in editing them.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the input. I guess [@ChrisF's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258628/216084) read together with [@Jason's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258626/how-important-are-correct-spellings-grammar-when-they-do-not-affect-the-under#comment37373_258628) sums up the discussion nicely.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you should be improving the spelling and grammar of posts - along with as many as possible of the other things that are wrong.

There are a number of reasons why this is useful.

1. It makes the posts easier to understand - especially for non-native English speakers. There's reduced ambiguity if the post is using the correct words in the correct order.
2. It makes the posts more discoverable by Google. Search engines will be able to find the questions and answers more easily.
3. It's professional. We're a site for professional people. We should be able to string a sentence together properly.

Comment: Still, don't leave other glaring problems, or it may be rejected as "too minor". Always mention the caveats for such blanket statements.

Comment: Also- I can't edit or I'd add this as #4- the person is way less likely to be helped. I know as soon as I see someone use "r" instead of "are" or "u" instead of "you", my first reaction is "well, they clearly don't care, so why should I?", and if it's bad enough I'll just move on. I doubt I'm the only one. Language barrier issues are one thing; I'll ignore that and move on; but pathological laziness is something I refuse to abide.

Comment: Based on my recent reading of Meta, I give it about a 50/50 chance that the edits are rejected as "too minor" regardless of whether there are other easily identifiable issues with the post.  Such a "minor" edit is as likely to be seen as "rep-whoring" as it is to be seen as legitimate, and there are any number of minor subjective issues that could be seen to suggest that the editor failed to fix everything.  That's not to say I disagree with anything you've said, but it's remiss not to note it as a gray area, and likely to lead to hit-or-miss edit-queue results.

Comment: Sorry to pipe in as well, but I recently had a spelling/grammatical correction refused by the author because (I believe) it was their 2nd language and either they saw no problem in their spelling or didn't want corrections associated with this rankings.

Should we just leave such things as they stand or contact the person to explain why you suggested such corrections? - as I believe that often (not in so much in this instance) bad grammar and spelling could change the meaning and as mentioned, certainly make it harder to understand for someone who's not native.

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of questions posed by people whose grasp of English is a little, shall we say, tenuous. If someone is skilled enough to understand the OP and what he/she is really asking, then it is of immeasurable help to other users trying to answer the question. A large number of IT professionals may be highly skilled but only have a limited grasp of English, and they are much more likely to be able to assist when a question is asked more precisely and correctly.

I dislike leaving minor grammatical and spelling errors - @ChrisF explains some of the reasons  in his answer. Personally I'm more annoyed by someone using bad English when it is their first language than when a non-native speaker phrases a question badly due to an incomplete understanding of English

Comment: Those with limited skills are more in need to see correct English, while for experts it feels relaxing to read proper English. Sadly only few users see corrections as a help to improve and learn from.

Answer (score 5):

grammer & speling isues r not criticle, but it can stil anoy the crap out of u.

We expect our users to put the minimal effort required to ask a coherent question without having us decipher his language, as well as his problem.

This is an English site, speak English. We are professionals, not some [other sites](http://answers.yahoo.com).

Comment: While on that topic: it annoys the crap out of me to see a post "edited" by a high-rep user, and on opening it, finding out that it was just a mis-placed tag that bothered this person. the rst of da post un touchet incl al glering obveous prlbsbmbs -- "kindly advanced thanks" and all.

Comment: @Jongware: That would be a different problem. That doesn't reduce the importance of fixing grammar errors.

Comment: It doesn't reduce the importance, but it is a sign that some people who'd one *expect* to care, actually do not.

Comment: @Jongware Or it's a sign the person doesn't have 30 minutes to fix everything and decided just to fix one quick thing that affects how the site actually works because that's all they have time for. (Disclaimer: I'm against the "too minor" reason for rejecting edits.)